# Steps in a double integration

Tags: integration

I used an online calculator to solve the following double integration:
[image: click]. I now know the answer, but no online calculator seems to show the steps leading to this answer, and I can't figure out how to do so. Can someone help with the steps leading to that answer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with polar coordinates $x=rcos(a), y=rsin(a)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* Change variables $x=r\cos\phi,\,y=r\sin\phi$ so that the integral becomes $$\iint_R \sqrt {1+\frac{r^2}{100}} r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\phi,$$ where the region $R$ is defined by $0\le\phi\le π/2\, 0\le r\le 10/\cos \phi, 0\le r\le 10/\sin\phi.$ However, since the integrand and the region are symmetrical about $y=x,$ you may split the integral into two equal parts, as follows:

$$\int_0^{π/4}\int_0^{10/\cos\phi}\sqrt {1+\frac{r^2}{100}}r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\phi+\int_{π/4}^{π/2}\int_0^{10/\sin\phi}\sqrt {1+\frac{r^2}{100}} r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\phi=2\int_0^{π/4}\int_0^{10/\cos\phi}\sqrt {1+\frac{r^2}{100}}r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\phi.$$

You should now be able to proceed.

Comment: Do I still use polar coordinates even though I'm finding the surface area of a shape that looks like a square from birds eye view?

Comment: I tried solving it following an example someone did on youtube but I ended up with the wrong answer. I'm sorry for asking for so much, but can you tell me what to do from here? @Allawonder

Comment: @abd.shd_247 Yes, your domain is a square (you're not finding an area, actually!). But that doesn't matter. Polar coordinates is just a change of variables. Here, it simplifies the integrand although it messes up with the limits a bit, but the tradeoff is still fair.

Comment: @abd.shd_247 To integrate from here, first integrate with respect to $r$ (the inner integral), then substitute the limits. Then do the outer integral. To do the under one is easy make the variable change $t=r^2,$ or set $\tan z=\frac{r}{100}.$

Comment: I have a small question: how did you get those ranges? The 0≤ϕ≤π/2 and 0≤r≤10/cosϕ and 0≤r≤10/sinϕ.

Comment: @abd.shd_247 The original ranges are $0\le x,\,y\le 10.$ Now perform the suggested substitutions.

Comment: I've done all the steps and it works! :) But I still can't seem to figure out how you went from 0≤x,y≤10 to the ranges you gave, but everything else makes sense!

Comment: @abd.shd_247 For example, recall that $x=r\cos\phi.$ Then since $0\le x\le 10,$ it means that $0\le r\cos\phi \le 10,$ from which we see that $\cos\phi>0$ (divide through by $r,$ which is positive), hence we can divide through by $\cos\phi$ to get the desired result.

Comment: I get it now!! Thank you so much for your help @Allawonder , I think you might have saved my IB Math HL Internal Assessment with your help :)

Comment: I have one final question, I'm really sorry haha. Why is it that after you separate the integrals, one had a  range of 10/cosϕ and the other 10/sinϕ? Is it because one is supposed to represent x and the other y, or is it because the first one lays on the x-axis, meaning the angle utilizes cosine and the second one lays on the y-axis, so the angle utilizes sine? Or is it a different reason

Comment: @abd.shd_247  *Is it because one is supposed to represent x and the other y,...* Yes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you for your efforts in helping me understand a topic I should clearly practice more haha.